# XML Etree parse with tags named the same

Tags: python, xml, pandas, elementtree

All, been trying to figure this out for a few days and while I think I'm close, It's just returning blanks since it's not grabbing the correct XML.

### Sample XML

```
<Attribute>
     <Name>Column1</Name>
     <Value>abcded</Value>
</Attribute>
<Attribute>
    <Name>Column2</Name>
    <Value>abcdef</Value>
</Attribute>
<Attribute>
    <Name>coumn3</Name>
    <Value>abcdef</Value>
</Attribute>
```

### Code

```
for node in parsed_xml.iter():
    Attributes = node.get.attrib('column1')
    correlationssnnamecount = node.find('column2')
    divphoneaddrcount = node.find('column3')

df_xml = df_xml.append(
    pd.Series([column1, getvalueofnode(column2),
               getvalueofnode(column3)], 
               index=dfcols),
               ignore_index=True)

print df_xml
```

What I'm looking for is basically my dataframe to have a heading of "column1" and the value, "column2", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the file was changed this is the solution
but please note for a valid xml file you will need something like

```
<data> ...</data>
```

at the start and end

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

inp=ET.parse("inputfile.xml")
inroot=inp.getroot()
ss={}

for child in inroot.iter('Attribute'):
    for n,v in zip(child.findall(".//Name"),child.findall(".//Value")):
        ss.update({n.text:v.text})

df=pd.DataFrame(ss,index=[0])

Out:
   Column1 Column2  coumn3
0  abcded  abcdef  abcdef
```

If your inputfile.xml is the xml file given here https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree

then it is

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

inp=ET.parse("inputfile.xml")
inroot=inp.getroot()

df=pd.DataFrame(columns= ['Country','rank','year','gdppc'])

ranks = inroot.findall(".//rank")
years = inroot.findall(".//year")
gdppc= inroot.findall(".//gdppc")

df['Country']=[child.attrib['name'] for child in inroot]
df['rank']=[r.text for r in ranks]
df['year']=[y.text for y in years]
df['gdppc'] = [g.text for g in gdppc]
```

This produces a dataframe as you request.

```
df:

      Country     rank  year  gdppc
0  Liechtenstein    1  2008  141100
1      Singapore    4  2011   59900
2         Panama   68  2011   13600
```

Comment: Hi Vipluv, thanks for the response.  Would this also work on the above .XML?  I was changing it as you were probably typing :(  As an added complexity, I have a bunch of .xml files within an S3 bucket which is why I was using the iterator.

Comment: oh.. this is quite different... so the findall thing might not help... as you would do  `inroot.findall(".//Name")` and get all the names and then `inroot.findall("//Values")`... you would need to use the child.attrib and child.tag, as shown here [https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html]

Comment: Yeah I've been trying to figure out the child.attrib and child.tag and I'm just not having much success unfortunately.

Comment: Yup, this works.  I just need to figure out how to get rid of all the noise in the .XML documents now since they don't contain a <data> and </data>..  This said, the solution works perfectly.